# null == object instead of object == null

Tags: language-agnostic, null

I've seen this in a few places, people using

```
if(null == myInstance)
```

instead of

```
if(myInstance == null)
```

Is the former just a matter of style or does it have any performance impact in front of the (more intuitive, in my opinion) latter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends actually on the language you are using.

In the languages where only `bool` type is recognized as a condition inside `if`, `if (myinstance == null)` is preferred as it reads more naturally.

In the languages where other types can be treated (implicitly casted, etc.) as a condition the form `if (null == myinstance)` is usually preferred. Consider, for example, C. In C, `int`s and pointers are valid inside if. Additionally, assignment is treated as an expression. So if one mistakenly writes `if (myinstance = NULL)`, this won't be detected by the compiler as an error. This is known to be a popular source of bugs, so the less readable but more reliable variant is recommended. Actually, some modern compilers issue a *warning* in case of assignment inside `if` (`while`, etc.), but not an *error*: after all, it's a valid expression in C.

Answer (score 1):

You do that, to avoid that you by mistake set the value of `myInstance` to `null`.

**Example for a typo:**

```
if (null = myConstant) // no problem here, just won't compile


if (myConstant = null) // not good. Will compile anyway.
```

In general a lot of developers will put the constant part of the equation in first position for that reason.

Writing conditional checks this way is also referred to as ***Yoda Conditions***.

Comment: You mean typing if(myInstance = null) instead of if(myInstance==null) ?

Comment: Exactly. There is a certain risk, that that may happen.